# How to check in a bash script if passed argument is file or directory?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have to write a simple bash script in Ubuntu which would allow me to pass it some arguments and I want to check if these arguments which can contain spaces are files or directories. How can I do this?

Comment: you want to check, if it is a file or directory using script?Explain a bit more.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes. If I run `./my_script file 1 file 2 file 3`, how can I check in the script if `file 1`, `file 2`, or `file 3` is a file or a directory or neither?

Comment: `if [[ -f $1 || -d $1]]` - will check the first argument of the script.

Comment: @Danatela The problem is that the filenames can have one or more spaces.

Comment: Then use double-quotes everywhere. Or you can escape spaces by backslash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Example script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# This is a simple demo script
# It takes 3 parameters and checks if they are files or directories

echo "Welcome to my script"

if [[ -f "$1" || -d "$1" ]]
then
    echo "The First argument is a file or directory"
fi

if [[ -f "$2" || -d "$2" ]]
then
    echo "The second argument is a file or directory"
fi

if [[ -f "$3" || -d "$3" ]]
then
    echo "The third argument is a file or directory"
fi

echo "Bye!"
```

### Example scenario

*I saved script as `~/script.sh` and did `chmod +x script.sh`*

```
karimov-danil@Karimov-Danil:~$ ./script.sh "Шаб лоны" "Обще доступные" "ta lk" 
Welcome to my script
The First argument is a file or directory
The second argument is a file or directory
The third argument is a file or directory
Bye!
```

Note: you should pass arguments inside double-quotes.