# How do I iterate the arguments in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Is there any method to iterate the passed arguments in a bash script? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/429235/234607) from my question shows me how to use each argument, but I want to iterate them because the number of arguments is variable.

I tried something like:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    if [[ -f "$($i)" ]]
    then
        echo "$($i) is a file"
    elif [[ -d "$($i)" ]]
    then
        echo "$($i) is a directory"
    else
        echo "$($i) is not a file or directory"
    fi
done
```

But it give me errors. I tried also to use without success `$$i` instead of `$($i)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `$@` to refer to all the arguments:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [[ -f "$arg" ]]
    then
        echo "$arg is a file"
    elif [[ -d "$arg" ]]
    then
        echo "$arg is a directory"
    else
        echo "$arg is not a file or directory"
    fi
done
```

See also: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST

Comment: +1 I just want to note the importance of quoting `"$@"` for arguments that may have spaces because I've seen some people forgetting that and leading to unexpected bugs.

Comment: As a special case for the argument list, you can drop the `in` part and use just `for arg; do ...`. You can use `shift` or `set` before the loop to remove arguments that need special handling (e.g. target directory).

Answer (score 0):

The use of `while + shift` seems more versatile to me:

```
while [ ! "$1" == "" ]; do
    case "$1" in
    "--mode" )
            MODE="$1 $2"
            shift
            ;;
    "--clean" )
            CLEAN="$1"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

You can, then pass arguments of variable length of terms.
Note that, in case of mode, it does an extra shift, besides the one before the end of the loop.

Comment: if you need to work with options, you may find [`getopt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) useful.

Comment: If you're going to do this, the condition should be `while [ -n "$1" ]`.